ERROR: Missing classes detected while running R8. Please add the missing classes or apply additional keep rules that are generated in
I finished testing my app but anytime I run flutter build apk or flutter build apk --release I run into this error
ERROR: Missing classes detected while running R8. Please add the missing classes or apply additional keep rules that are generated in C:\Users\HP\Downloads\Friendnpal_flutter-main\Friendnpal_flutter-main\build\flutter_inappwebview\outputs\mapping\release\missing_rules.txt.
ERROR: R8: Missing class android.window.BackEvent (referenced from: void io.flutter.view.FlutterView.startBackGesture(android.window.BackEvent) and 1 other context)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_inappwebview:minifyReleaseWithR8'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.R8Task$R8Runnable
   > Compilation failed to complete

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 35s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           36.7s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

I tried copying what was in my missing.txt file to my proguard rules, Here are my proguard rules
# Please add these rules to your existing keep rules in order to suppress warnings.
# This is generated automatically by the Android Gradle plugin.
-dontwarn android.window.BackEvent
# https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/78625#issuecomment-804164524
#-keep class io.flutter.app.** { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugin.** { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.util.** { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.view.** { *; }
#-keep class io.flutter.** { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugins.** { *; }


Sorry, but what is the question here? Did adding -dontwarn android.window.BackEvent not work?

Add this in the android/build.gradle file at the top.
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {
        if (it.name == "flutter_inappwebview_android") {
            it.android.buildTypes.release.minifyEnabled = false
        }
    }
}

this worked for me.
If this does not work for you, You can refer this for more

Don't turn off optimizations for release.

Good afternoon,
in my case I was missing the proguard-rules.pro file in android/app folder
I created it and added the following content
-ignorewarnings
-keep class * {
  public private *;
 }

If after adding the file you still get errors you could test by adding the following into your pubspec.yaml file
dependency_overrides:
# TODO: Recheck once flutter_inappwebview version >6.0.0 is released
flutter_inappwebview_android:
  git:
    url: https://github.com/holzgeist/flutter_inappwebview
    path: flutter_inappwebview_android
    ref: d89b1d32638b49dfc58c4b7c84153be0c269d057

I hope this helps you to fix your issue as it did for me.
